# (coc.nvim) RLS warning: ...use crate_blacklist instead

Tags: plugin-coc

I've got a warning on start:

`[coc.nvim] RLS configuration option use_crate_blacklist is deprecated: use crate_blacklist instead`

Probably I have to put into my `coc-settings.json` "rust.crate_blacklist" option as suggested [here](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-rls). Unfortunately, I've no idea in what context I have to put it. Examples are precious few, and Google won't help.

In my `coc-settings.json` there is no mention of Rust since I use `coc-rls` extension.